# Why does INDEX/MATCH print 0 instead of what I expect in EXCEL

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I just started using INDEX/MATCH function in Excel and have no idea why it is printing only 0

```
=INDEX(DATA!$B:$B, MATCH(index!$C3, DATA!$A:$A,0))
```

So Im using the expression above and have no trouble with the result.

However when I try to print the column with Korean (DATA!$C:$C) it shows only 0

other than C column it has no problem printing out :( ($D:$D, $E:$E,... and so on has no problem)

Comment: Why second `INDEX` inside `MATCH()` function. Try- `=INDEX(DATA!$B:$B, MATCH($C3, DATA!$A:$A,0))`

Comment: @Harun24hr Isn't the OP just referencing a cell from a worksheet called `index`? As they say "Im using the expression above and have no trouble with the result.".

Comment: Seems like OP is referencing to sheet named Index here.

Answer (score 0):

When the value returned by `INDEX` is blank, Excel often interprets it as a number (0).

There are a number of ways to rectify it. If you want the result to always be a string, you can simply add an empty string onto the end of the result:

```
 =INDEX(DATA!$B:$B, MATCH(index!$C3, DATA!$A:$A,0)) & ""
```

If you are not sure if it will return a number or a string, you can wrap your formula in an `IF` to force blanks to return as an empty string instead of a number:

```
=IF(
    INDEX(DATA!$B:$B, MATCH(index!$C3, DATA!$A:$A,0))="",
    "",
    INDEX(DATA!$B:$B, MATCH(index!$C3, DATA!$A:$A,0))
)
```